# How to rename the columns starting with 'abcd' to starting with 'wxyz' in Spark Scala?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

How can I rename the columns starting with `abcd` to starting with `wxyz`.

List of columns: `abcd_name, abcd_id, abcd_loc, empId, empCode`

I need to change the names of columns in a dataframe that starts with `abcd`

Required column list: `wxyz_name, wxyz_id, wxyz_loc, empId, empCode`

I tried getting all the columns' lists using the below code, but not sure how to implement it.

```
val df_cols_abcd = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("abcd")).map(df(_))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with `foldLeft`:

```
val oldPrefix = "abcd"
val newPrefix = "wxyz"
val newDf = df.columns
  .filter(_.startsWith(oldPrefix))
  .foldLeft(df)((acc, oldName) =>
    acc.withColumnRenamed(oldName, newPrefix + oldName.substring(oldPrefix.length))
  )
```

Your first idea to filter columns with `startWith` is correct. The only think you miss the the part where you rename all the columns.

I recommend to do some research about `foldLeft` if you're not familiar with. The idea is the following:

- I start with an initial dataframe (`df` in the first brackets).
- I will apply a function to it with each of the columns I need to rename (the function is the one in the second brackets). This function takes as argument an accumulator (`acc`) that is an intermediate dataframe (because it will rename the columns one at a time), and another argument which is the current element of the list (here the list contains the name of the columns that need to be modified).

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it really worked. Appreciate it thank you

Comment: Got a clear understanding of foldLeft, thank you